# docker on RHEL - Error: Package: policycoreutils-python-2.5-8.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)

Tags: docker, rhel

when trying to do a `yum install docker-engine` on our RHEL 7.2 server I get the following error:

```
Error: Package: policycoreutils-python-2.5-8.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
           Requires: policycoreutils = 2.5-8.el7
           Installed: policycoreutils-2.5-9.el7.x86_64 (@rhel-7-server-rpms)
               policycoreutils = 2.5-9.el7
           Available: policycoreutils-2.2.5-11.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-eus-rpms)
               policycoreutils = 2.2.5-11.el7
           Available: policycoreutils-2.2.5-11.el7_0.1.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-eus-rpms)
               policycoreutils = 2.2.5-11.el7_0.1
           Available: policycoreutils-2.2.5-15.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-eus-rpms)
               policycoreutils = 2.2.5-15.el7
           Available: policycoreutils-2.2.5-20.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-eus-rpms)
               policycoreutils = 2.2.5-20.el7
           Available: policycoreutils-2.5-8.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               policycoreutils = 2.5-8.el7
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Thing is, the packages are there...

```
yum list policycoreutils-python
policycoreutils-python.x86_64                                                                           2.5-8.el7

yum list policycoreutils
policycoreutils.x86_64                                                                              2.5-9.el7
```

Comment: Which version of Linux kernel are you using?

Comment: 3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64

Comment: I had some troubles with docker with old kernel but after kernel was updated it to 4.4+ problems disappears. So you can try update kernel. I am not 100% sure that this will fix this issue but you can try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, with your kernel specified you seem to actually be on 7.3.  I would do a "yum makecache" and then try again.  I am curious if you had stale repodata or if there is another issue.

Not that it should matter, but what happens if you try a "yum install policycoreutils" ?

Comment: bunch of funny stories here which include the fact that the server was not upgraded properly.  It ended up being a supposed known issue with RHEL concerning their subscription manager for some reason our server was linking the Japan repos.  our SA corrected this issue which allowed me to do a yum for the policycoreutils-python and it installed.  we're all good now.